# How does one physically achieve a constant state variable process in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

Recently, I was studying about the various different paths which we can go through in thermodynamics,  and, I wish to ask how exactly we can achieve a process such as a  constant temperature or constant volume process.

And, by the way, aren't all processes constant volume? because we define volume as the size of container.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at thermodynamic cycles and processes, it is important to note that we're often only talking about *ideal* processes, which enables us to talk about controlling various state properties in particular ways that make the analysis easier. In real systems, they are only at best *approximately* modeled by keeping something constant.

There are some classic ways to define systems that control specific state variables:

- *Constant volume* processes occur inside a closed container made of perfectly rigid walls. This means the volume is fixed, so we've enforced our desired property.
- *Constant pressure* processes occur in an elastic container, or in something like an open container or a container with a piston applying a constant force. Here, the volume will change as the process occurs, but the elastic walls or the ambient conditions ensure the pressure stays constant.
- *Constant temperature* processes happen inside a big, ambient bath and require that whatever heat is generated/lost by the process is immediately replaced by the bath. This means the process has to happen slow enough relative to the conduction into the bath.
- *Constant entropy* processes have no losses, so this means there can be no heat transfer into/out of the system and there can be no friction or other dissipation mechanisms. Usually this requires ideal, frictionless fluids.

You can of course define other ways to keep different state properties constant if it is useful to you. I can't stress this enough though -- these are only *idealized* conditions that serve as a useful model! In real life, nothing is perfectly constant anything, but the models can still be useful.